# SharePoint menu options - how to go beyond 2 levels

Tags: hyperlink

With SharePoint 2010, we've noticed that the left-side navigation from the master page limits us to two levels -- "Add Heading" and "Add Link." We'd like to have a menu on the left that has at least one more level, like "Add Sub-Link". Are there ways to do this while not changing the master page?

Also, if we have a link that's related to that section of the site but not on the menu, if we navigate to it, the left navigation highlights the root item. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution to the problem of adding/removing items on the Quick Launch menu and setting permissions on them: http://www.mtelligent.com/journal/2007/10/7/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-with-spnavigationnode-spna.html. I've placed pages into folders inside of the Pages library and will fetch and add them, based on the folder name, to the appropriate location on the Quick Launch menu.

This is for 2007 but should work for 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to customize the master page to do what you want. You can customize it, but even if you got more subheadings, the default navigation editor is only going to work at a 2 level instance. I really think that you would have to use some other means (custom code or jquery) to accomplish what you are looking for. I think I have seen a few examples out there for doing something like this.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have those examples of how folks have done it with jQuery (to not touch the master page)?